# Issue with saving/restoring state of navigation controller state

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have an issue with the case when the Activity is destroyed if it's been a long time in the background (also reproducible with the don't keep Activity developer option).

So, I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must call setGraph() before
> calling getGraph()

on this line of code (multiple graphs, that's why .graph is used to get the current one)

```
val myViewModel: MyViewModel = by navGraphViewModels(findNavController().graph.id) {
                    defaultViewModelProviderFactory
     }
```

which needs to be called after onCreate() blocks.

Then I implemented a mechanism to save navigation controller state by using this code:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        savedInstanceState.putBundle("nav_state", findNavController().saveState())
    }
```

and restoring it like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        findNavController().restoreState(savedInstanceState?.getBundle("nav_state"))
    }
```

And I get the error again since the state is not restored.

Did anyone have an issue similar to this? Is this the right approach to handle these issues?

I'm using 2.3.5. version of the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

restoring navigation state in catch block as below does the trick for me

```
try {
       val graph = findNavController().navInflater.inflate(navGraphId)
       findNavController().graph = graph
        
     } catch (e:`IllegalStateException) {              
 findNavController().restoreState(savedInstanceState?.getBundle("nav_state"))
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me:

Saving the navController

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    savedInstanceState.putBundle("nav_state", findNavController().saveState())
}
```

Restoring the navController

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    findNavController().restoreState(savedInstanceState?.getBundle("nav_state"))
}
```

And then, delay the viewModel

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    view.post { 
        viewModel.doSoemthing()
    }
}
```